# Android NDK advantages and disadvantages

Tags: c++, android, android-ndk

I am studying Android NDK. What are the advantages and disadvantages of NDK?
Are there any good references to study Android NDK?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you read the [official Android developer page regarding NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html)?

Quote:

> The Android NDK is a companion tool to
>   the Android SDK that lets you build
>   performance-critical portions of your
>   apps in native code. It provides
>   headers and libraries that allow you
>   to build activities, handle user
>   input, use hardware sensors, access
>   application resources, and more, when
>   programming in C or C++. If you write
>   native code, your applications are
>   still packaged into an .apk file and
>   they still run inside of a virtual
>   machine on the device. The fundamental
>   Android application model does not
>   change.
>
> Using native code does not result in
>   an automatic performance increase, but
>   always increases application
>   complexity. If you have not run into
>   any limitations using the Android
>   framework APIs, you probably do not
>   need the NDK.

So, unless you're doing some very performance intensive stuff that will choke your application when programming in Java, I'd suggest you stay clear of NDK. It's messier and more difficult to write NDK code properly unless you really know what you're doing and have strong knowledge of C and/or C++.

Comment: any free ndk book available or not...how to study ndk fully give me your suggestions please.....

Comment: There is no free book on the NDK. Official docs are inside the NDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#docs