# C++ or Java for android?

Tags: java, c++, android

I am thinking about picking up android development in my free time.  I see that development is possible in Java and C++ but the latter is limited.

I am much more comfortable with C++.

So my question is what limitations exist with C++ on Android?  Will I be able to develop full apps with it, or will I eventually have to learn Java?

Comment: This isn't answer, so I'll just comment: Now would be a great opportunity for you to learn Java. Never be afraid to pick up a new language.

Comment: is seems from other questions you have posted, you are familiar with c#, the switch from c# to java (and vice versa) is almost trivial...

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836509/android-ndk-advantage-and-disadvantage ?

Comment: I would go Java... if you're asking the question, Java vs C++, Java's hotspot will probably do wonders to your code and C++ will drag you to a slow overflow of dead! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pick the right tool for the job. The right tool for android is java, and occasionally c++ if it's really needed. Android runs on several different CPUs, and you'd be required to deal with fun stuff like compiling for platforms that you can't really test on - at least if you want to make apps for anyone but yourself.

Answer (score 7):

It's all dependent on what you want to do, but the general rule of thumb:

C++ is for speed (for example games).

Java is for UI and general Android programming.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but... as  both Java and C will be run on the same virtual machine, will C have significant speed boost over Java here?

Comment: I thought the C++ code was run directly (not through the JVM).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot code an entire Android application using only C++, the android SDK is written in Java and that is what you will have to use.

This said you can still use C++ for heavy stuff.

Comment: This is not entirely true.  With android 2.3+, and the ndk r5, you can build an entirely native android app.  http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html