# Using C++ and Java for Android Development (using togther not one or the other)

Tags: java, android, c++, database

***EDIT: Different than Java vs C++, I am asking about using them TOGETHER***

There are many questions asking whether to use Java vs C++ for android development, with debates about performance, complexity, and available APIs. I am curious as to if you can use C++ AND Java to make an android app, and if so, which should be used for what and how do they interact with each other.

My idea was to use them as follows:
**C++** - Database calls, complex algorithms, anything that requires faster performance
**Java** - API calls, UI/UX, etc.

Basically, which functions of a client/server app serving media files and information would benefit in performance from C++ vs which should just be in Java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ or Java for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628518/c-or-java-for-android)

Comment: @0X0nosugar Did you even read my question? I am not attempting to use Java or C++ I'm curious about using them TOGETHER. Using C++ for anything that requires performance and Java for UI and API calls

Comment: It seems to me that some of the answers to the other question are valid for your question as well.

Comment: The question you linked is more general yes it possible and sometimes you use both, depending on your app. I'm wondering what functions of an app would benefit in performance from C++ vs which ones to implement in Java

Comment: Your question has 0 context regarding the type of app you want to make. Assuming you're talking exclusively about client side development, performance will generally only come into play for games. It really makes no sense to introduce a new language as well as complexity and huge testing issues (and arguably scalability problems) to optimise a db call. If your question is really asking about implementing high time complexity algorithms, you'll need to provide context to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only 3 real reasons to drop into C or C++.

1)You're writing complex logic that needs to run on multiple platforms.  This means it can be shared between multiple platforms (iOS, Android, PC, Mac, Linux, and pretty much any embedded platform.  Anything but front end web).

2)There's an existing C or C++ library you want to use, and need to write Java JNI bindings.

3)You have to write very performant code.  Pretty much only games, video processing, and numerical processing fall here.  DB calls do not-  they aren't very time consuming (the db itself can be, but the DB itself is generally written in C already).  And if you think that calling a DB is an issue-  I don't think you have a good grasp on what actually takes time in programs.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I'm looking to develop the app and the server logic myself, and I was curious as to if any C++ would be required for the app itself or if it would only be required on the server. Sorry if my question was vague or poorly worded.

Answer (score 0):

Just as many of us did at the beginning I think you would first have to play by creating your "hello word" Android application in which of course you will use Java.

Afterwards, when you understand a bit how an Android app is constructed, you can try installing the NDK and try to implement some native function in C/C++. You will see the interface between both parts has limitations.

Making assumptions about if I will use one language or another without knowing the structure is meaningless.

Comment: I've began learning how android Java apps are structured, I have learned fragments, intents, activities, and event listeners, I'm not trying to make blind assumptions I'm attempting to plan the app before I make it, getting people opinions on when the use of C++ is useful vs when the performance of Java is close enough that using C++ is not worth it.